# Am I doing it wrong by downvoting a answer, which misleads OP?

Tags: discussion

I downvoted on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200958/javascript-charat0-gives-unexpected-results/23201035#answer-23201035). And he gave the following comment:

> Does it really qualify as a downvote when you usually don't have to
>   support IE7? Would you also downvote an answer telling one to use
>   .filter for an array with undefined values, since IE8 and below treats
>   this the wrong way?

He said that his' was a shorter version of what OP was doing.

I downvoted him, because OP was correct at doing `.charAt()` as bracket notation doesn't work in IE (*should I mention 7* ;).

I thought he was misleading already correct OP to use wrong thing.

When someone comments like this, I feel kinda guilty, and want to know if I'm right or wrong.

Did I do it right?

---

Some people are getting me wrong that I'm a supporter of IE. I'm not the person who likes IE.

But `.charAt()` has the advantages of being cross-browser and returns `""` in case the index isn't really there, whereas `[]` returns `undefined`.

Comment: If it bothers you, then put in a comment, but a *downvote* for being incompatible with IE 7. Sheesh! It would be a different matter if the OP had specified the need for IE 7 compatibility.

Comment: I feel there's a difference in not supporting IE7, or *failing* on IE7, @Louis. (Especially when there's a perfectly okay alternative, which was already posted as an answer.)

Comment: @Louis, check out my update. I hate IE, if you think I like it

Comment: @AmitJoki: I think it's inappropriate to write you "hate" IE in the question. As developers we're to justify actions based on technical correctness, not personal opinions.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT, done. edited

Comment: It would appear the answer in question been deleted.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT, yes. You're right

Comment: IE7 and lower have very little market share, telling someone not to use indexer for .charAt for that reason is pretty bad (however, it gives the illusion that you can assign to it which is a more legitimate reason I think people dislike [] notation for strings). I would definitely not downvote an answer for suggesting a technology that works in IE8+ (even IE9+) since IE6-7 are practically gone from most parts of the world. That said, like has been pointed out it's definitely _your_ choice to make.

Answer (score 8):

Upvotes and downvotes are yours to use however you wish (so long as you don't engage in voter fraud), and you're never obligated to explain them.

That said, guidance for using your votes can be found in the tooltip for each arrow.  On answers, the downvote tooltip says:

> This answer is not useful

That's the metric you should use when you downvote.

Comment: so did I do it right or wrong?

Comment: Is the answer you downvoted useful?

Comment: **I** don't think so

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you don't consider voting should be done by correctness? A incorrect answer can be certainly useful at times, but then I'd say it'd belong in a comment, rather than answer.

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen - MSFT: An incorrect answer by nature cannot be useful. At least, that's what I believe.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT Any incorrect information that might be useful would almost always be a *lot* more useful if that same post stated that the given information was technically incorrect, with as much explanation as is feasible (perhaps because it's an oversimplification, or an analogy that you admit has holes, or whatever) rather than an incorrect solution portrayed as a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Downvoting is fine.  You can downvote anything you want.  However, it is usually a good idea to explain your downvote, and when you downvote you are encouraged to do so.

Some people will always be offended by downvotes (and, on occasion, it leads to serial downvoting, but those will be adjusted by the system).  However, when accompanied by an explanation it may lead the OP to delete his own comment if he realizes or recognizes that your explanation is valid.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would have commented explaining that it doesn't work in IE7 and not downvoted. Imperfect solutions are okay if they add good information. Imperfect solutions that mislead someone into shooting herself in the foot are less okay and I would downvote. Whether not supporting IE7 fits that bill is debatable. I'd say no, you said yes, I don't see a big deal.

Bottom line, not everyone's going to agree. That's why we allow multiple upvotes and downvotes from many users.